# is there a way to call custom function with Aggregation query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have below document structure:

```
{
   Id: 1,
   StartDate: <any date>,
   EndDate: <any date>,
   TotalValue: <any double value>
}
```

I want one array in output which contains each date between StartDate and EndDate with value, which is TotalValue divided by days difference of StartDate, EndDate.

So result would look like this:

```
{
   Id: 1,
   StartDate: <any date>,
   EndDate: <any date>,
   Allocations: [{date: date1, val: TotalValue/number of Days}, {date: date2, val: TotalValue/number of Days},,,,{date: daten, val: TotalValue/number of Days}]
}
```

*[ Updated on 17-Feb ]*

Now, need to go a step deeper than this. Suppose, I have situation where, for few objects in array of root objects, I might got allocations array too, but not day-wise. I would be getting that range wise. So array might look like this:

```
{
   Id: 1,
   StartDate: ISODate("2019-01-01"),
   EndDate: ISODate("2019-12-31"),
   TotalValue: 3500,
   Allocations: [{startDate: ISODate("2019-01-01"), endDate: ISODate("2019-07-30"), val: 2000}, {startDate: ISODate("2019-07-01"), endDate: ISODate("2019-12-31"), val: 1500}]
},
{
   Id: 1,
   StartDate: ISODate("2020-01-01"),
   EndDate: ISODate("2020-12-31"),
   TotalValue: 5000
}
```

So in any variant, I would like to see datewise allocations. If allocations are already provided, use that to calculate daily, otherwise divide TotalValue evenly.

Comment: `val: TotalValue/number of Days`: So, the value will be same for all elements in the `Allocations` array.

Comment: yes, that's right @prasad_

Comment: Then, why do you want it in each element of the array? You can have a single field outside the array.

Comment: main requirement here is to generate above array which I need to use in later stages of pipeline, for example, group by date.

Comment: so basically, I thought of a approach where I could pass startdate, enddate and value to custom function which would return array just the way I wanted. Very interested to see if that is possible, or open for other workarounds too.

Comment: I posted an answer which gives the `Allocations` array as described in your post - **uses an agaregation query**.

Comment: @prasad_ any idea about latest addtion I made to question?

Comment: How do you do this calculation - _"If allocations are already provided, use that to calculate daily"_?Please post an example.

Comment: It would basically apply same logic, value divided by number of days. so in my given example, for first element of array, it should generate 181 array items with respective dates(starting from 2019-01-01 to 2019-06-30) and val should be 2000/181. And for second element, it should generate 184 array items with respective dates(starting from 2019-07-01 to 2019-12-31) and val should be 1500/184.

Comment: I will post the updated query later in the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This aggregation gives the desired output of `Allocations`. Using the following as an *example input document*:

```
{
   _id : ObjectId("5e42154155533a54ed5fb852"),
   Id: 1,
   StartDate: ISODate("2020-01-30"),
   EndDate: ISODate("2020-02-05"),
   TotalValue: 100
}
```

*The query:*

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          daysArr: { 
              $range: [ 0, { $add: [ { $divide: [ { $subtract: [ "$EndDate", "$StartDate" ] }, 86400000 ] } , 1 ] } ] 
          } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          Allocations: { 
              $map: {
                  input: "$daysArr",
                  in: { 
                      date: { $add: [ "$StartDate", { $multiply: [ 86400000, "$$this" ] } ] },
                      val: { $divide: [ "$TotalValue", { $add: [ { $divide: [ { $subtract: [ "$EndDate", "$StartDate" ] }, 86400000 ] }, 1 ] } ] }
                   }
               }
          }
      } 
  },
  { 
      $project: { daysArr: 0 } 
  }
] )
```

*The output document:*

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e42154155533a54ed5fb852"),
        "Id" : 1,
        "StartDate" : ISODate("2020-01-30T00:00:00Z"),
        "EndDate" : ISODate("2020-02-05T00:00:00Z"),
        "TotalValue" : 100,
        "Allocations" : [
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2020-01-30T00:00:00Z"),
                    "val" : 14.285714285714286
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2020-01-31T00:00:00Z"),
                    "val" : 14.285714285714286
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "val" : 14.285714285714286
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2020-02-02T00:00:00Z"),
                    "val" : 14.285714285714286
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2020-02-03T00:00:00Z"),
                    "val" : 14.285714285714286
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2020-02-04T00:00:00Z"),
                    "val" : 14.285714285714286
            },
            {
                    "date" : ISODate("2020-02-05T00:00:00Z"),
                    "val" : 14.285714285714286
            }
    ]
}
```

---

[ Updated as per the enhancement of 17-Feb ]

This aggregation will take care of the two types of input documents:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e4a16e96d13751bfb64572d"),
        "Id" : 1,
        "StartDate" : ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "EndDate" : ISODate("2019-12-12T00:00:00Z"),
        "TotalValue" : 3500,
        "Allocations" : [
                {
                        "startDate" : ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "endDate" : ISODate("2019-01-10T00:00:00Z"),
                        "val" : 2000
                },
                {
                        "startDate" : ISODate("2019-01-11T00:00:00Z"),
                        "endDate" : ISODate("2019-01-12T00:00:00Z"),
                        "val" : 1500
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e42154155533a54ed5fb852"),
        "Id" : 11,
        "StartDate" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "EndDate" : ISODate("2020-02-05T00:00:00Z"),
        "TotalValue" : 100
}
```

*The aggregation query:*

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          Allocations: { 
              $ifNull: [ 
                  "$Allocations", 
                  [ { startDate: "$StartDate", endDate: "$EndDate", val: "$TotalValue" } ] 
              ] 
          }
      }
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          Allocations: {
              $map: {
                  input: "$Allocations", 
                  in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [ 
                          "$$this", 
                          { range: { 
                                 $range: [ 
                                     0, 
                                    { $add: [ { $divide: [ { $subtract: [ "$$this.endDate", "$$this.startDate" ] }, 86400000 ] } , 1 ] } 
                                 ] 
                          } }
                      ]
                  }
              } 
          } 
      }
  },
  { 
      $unwind: "$Allocations" 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          Allocations: { 
              $map: {
                  input: "$Allocations.range",
                  in: { 
                      date: { $add: [ "$Allocations.startDate", { $multiply: [ 86400000, "$$this" ] } ] },
                      val: { $divide: [ "$Allocations.val", { $size: "$Allocations.range" } ] }
                   }
               }
          }
      } 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: "$_id", 
          Allocations: { $push: "$Allocations" }, 
          doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" } 
    } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: {
          "doc.Allocations": { 
              $reduce: { 
                  input: "$Allocations", initialValue: [ ],
                  in: { $concatArrays : ["$$value", "$$this"] }
              } 
          } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$doc" } 
  }
] )
```

Comment: One assumption I am making is the number of days (the dates difference) is calculated as, e.g., for the dates "2020-01-30" and "2020-02-05" the number of days is considered as 7 (includes start and end dates).

Comment: Updated the answer for the enhancements.